# 3rd highest salary in each department

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following tables: https://pastebin.com/Js0Sm69S (`CREATE` and `INSERT` statements).

I would like to find the third-highest salary in each department if there is such.

I was able to achieve this:
[image]
Using the following query:

```
SELECT *,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER 
       (PARTITION BY DepartmentId ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS DRank
FROM Employees
```

I am not sure if `DENSE_RANK()` is the best ranking function to use here. Maybe not, because `WHERE DRank=3` may return more than one result (but we can say `TOP(1)`). What do you think about this? Now how to display the third-highest salary in each department if there is such?

Comment: It sounds like you already answered your question: just pick the top 1, because rows that have the same rank will have the same value they're ranked by, so whatever `top 1` happens to return, it'll have the same value there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select EmployeeID,FirstName,DepartmentID,Salary
 From (
Select *
      ,RN  = Row_Number() over (Partition By DepartmentID Order By Salary)
      ,Cnt = sum(1) over (Partition By DepartmentID)
 From  Employees
      ) A
 Where RN = case when Cnt<3 then Cnt else 3 end
```

Comment: What is the `where` clause doing?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there, but you can achieve this with `ROW_NUMBER`, instead of `DENSE_RANK`. I think following query should help.

```
WITH cte AS
(
   SELECT *,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DepartmentId ORDER BY Salary DESC) AS DRank
   FROM Employees
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE DRank= 3
```